# How to convert splunk curl query into Rcurl

Tags: r, rcurl, splunk

I want to convert this particular splunk curl request into Rcurl:

curl -k -u admin:pass https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs --get -d search="eventCount>100"

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all you should read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question; a good question has better changes to be solved and you to receive help. On the other hand a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is also good. It explains how to create a reproducible example in R. Help users to help you by providing a piece of your data a desired output and things you have tried so far... and last: of course we cannot see *your* local host!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however no one can share the server and other details in forum. This is as is example from splunk doc itself so its quite reproducible with parameters replaced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This provides an idiom via `httr` you can extrapolate from for other Splunk calls:

```
#' @param search_terms
#' @param other parameters passed to httr GET/POST request
#' @return data.frame of results
search_now <- function(search_terms, ...) {

  require(httr)

  # i.e. "https://localhost:8089"
  splunk_server <- Sys.getenv("SPLUNK_API_SERVER")
  username <- Sys.getenv("SPLUNK_USERNAME")
  password <- Sys.getenv("SPLUNK_PASSWORD")

  search_job_export_endpoint <- "servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export"

  response <- GET(splunk_server,
                   path=search_job_export_endpoint,
                   encode="form",
                   config(ssl_verifyhost=FALSE, ssl_verifypeer=0),
                   authenticate(username, password),
                   query=list(search=paste0("search ", search_terms, collapse="", sep=""),
                              output_mode="csv"),
                   verbose(), ...)

  result <- read.table(text=content(response, as="text"), sep=",", header=TRUE,
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  result

}
```

It expects the server base URL to be in `SPLUNK_API_SERVER` environment variable (stick them in `.Renvion`) and the username and password to be in those other two really obvious variables in the code.

I had that lying around in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/7e9adebb30936994de36) for someone else so glad it gets some more mileage. A full `splunkr` package is in the works.

Comment: nice! is the `splunkr` package ready?? :)