# splunk rest api search using R

Tags: api, curl, rcurl, splunk, httr

I am trying to replicate the curl method mentioned in splunk rest api doc into R to perform search using R. Sorry, I won't be able provides details on the parameters to replicate. Hence attaching the [link for reference](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTTUT/RESTsearches#Create_a_search_job).

```
curl -u admin:changeme -k https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="search *"
```

This returns me a sid from curl. However when I try to replicate the same in R using httr it returns  list of all search details. I have tried using both POST & GET in httr just in case. Below is sample code. Ideally below one should return me a sid. however it returns list of existing search details. Not sure what I am missing. I am new to Rcurl,httr. I tried curlperform as well, there also same. Seems, something is missing out. What exactly -d does in curl, is this the thing I am missing to replicate ?

```
response <- GET(splunk_server,path=search_job_export_endpoint,
                    config(ssl_verifyhost=FALSE, ssl_verifypeer=0),
                   authenticate(username, password),
                   query=list(search=urlencode(search_terms)),                             
                   verbose())

  result <- read.table(text=content(response, as="text"), sep=",", header=TRUE,
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I found one similar issue but here the platform used is java. http://filecentral.us/is-d-of-curl-the-same-as-formdata-in-xmlhttprequest-post/

Comment: See if this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276780/how-to-convert-splunk-curl-query-into-rcurl - helps. If so, I can mark this as a dup.

Comment: Its similar, and giving the same output